# Rearrange a cell with multiple values alphabetically [Excel]

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file where I have a cell with multiple values, split by a comma. For instance: New York, Chicago, Los Angeles. Now I want to rearrange this cell in alphatical order, like: Chicago, Los Angeles, New York. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: See this post for a macro that apparently does what you request : https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/3okezz/sorting_words_in_an_excel_cell_by_alphabetical/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Following code will read values in Column `A` and give the desired result in Column `B`.

```
Sub SortString()
    Dim MyArray As Variant, varSwap As Variant
    Dim i As Long, min As Long, max As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim IsSwapped As Boolean

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set MyRange = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    For Each cell In MyRange
        MyArray = Split(cell.Value, ",")

        min = LBound(MyArray)
        max = UBound(MyArray) - 1
        Do
            IsSwapped = False
            For i = min To max
                If MyArray(i) > MyArray(i + 1) Then
                    varSwap = MyArray(i)
                    MyArray(i) = MyArray(i + 1)
                    MyArray(i + 1) = varSwap
                    IsSwapped = True
                End If
            Next
            max = max - 1
        Loop Until Not IsSwapped

        For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
            Debug.Print MyArray(i)
            If str = "" Then
                str = Trim(MyArray(i))
            Else
                str = str & ", " & Trim(MyArray(i))
            End If
        Next i
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = str
        str = ""
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. This almost works, except that it stores the first value in the cell always at the end. for example:

a, b, f, l, o, u, i, z, x, y gives b, f, i, l, o, u, x, y, z, a

Comment: @user30058 - let me check.

Comment: @user30058 - Just replace the line `If MyArray(i) > MyArray(i + 1) Then` with `If Trim(MyArray(i)) > Trim(MyArray(i + 1)) Then`. Spaces might be giving issues here. Let me know if its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in A1, use text to columns with a delimited width and select the comma as your separator. When the cells are split, select them all and sort alphabetically. Then in a different cell use,

```
=A1 & ", " & B1 & ", " C1
```

And so on. If you want this in VBA (as per your tag) a good starting point will be to do the above whilst recording a macro, then edit to your needs.

EDIT

This is by no means pretty, but its a starting point to use VBA to run through each row.

```
Dim i As Integer, lastRow As Integer, curRng As Range

lastRow = Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
Cells(i, 1).Select
Set curRng = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight))
    curRng.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=curRng, _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange curRng
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: How do I sort them alphabetically per column? If, in this example B1 becomes New York, C1 Chicaco and D1 Los Angeles. How do I rearrange them to become B1 Chicago, C1 LA and D1 NY? I have 450.000 rows with each having a cell with 1 to 4 values in the cell. I need them all sorted per row

Answer (score 0):

Use the SPLIT function to first store your comma separated value list in an array, then sort the array in any way you wish, then use the JOIN function to create a comma separated value list again.

For example:

```
myArray = SPLIT(Cell.Value, ",")
Call SomeSortFunction(myArray)
myString = JOIN(myArray, ",")
Cell.Value = myString
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the string of values from the cell into a function and then loop through the list splitting on comma:

```
Array = Split(yourString, ",")
```

Then loop through it:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(Array)
```

To find the first letter of each value I would use something like:

```
Left(Array(i), Len(Array(i)) - 1)
```

You can then sort it alphabetically. You could use [SUBSTITUTE()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) function to swap values around.